# leading zero in LoopingSelector windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, int

I have created a looping selector of numbers from 0 to 99.
I want it to display, all numbers under 10 with a leading 0, so for example, I want 1 to be displayed as 01. 
I researched but couldn't find anything regarding to this.

I got this far,

```
LoopingSelector1.DataSource = new IntLoopingDataSource()
            { 
                MinValue = 0,
                MaxValue = 10, 
                Increment = 1, 
                SelectedItem = 0 
            };
```

Even changing MinValue to '00', it doesn't display the leading zero.

I welcome any ideas. 
Thanks

Comment: use a text looping data source, then parse the selected text to int.  Or use an IValueConverter to convert the int to a string before it displays in the control.

Comment: I have no clue how to do it, is there any example or something like?

Comment: :/ where you see "int" change it to "string".  When you get the current value, convert from string to int.  Its close to trivial.

Comment: Still can't find my way into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a string-based datasource as Will suggested, you can override the itemtemplate to display the numbers the way you like:

```
    <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector ItemSize="100,100">
        <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=\{0:d2\}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, now all numbers below 10 are displayed with a leading 0, that is great..the only problem I am having right now is displaying the selected number in a textBlock, when the number is below 10 it won't display the leading 0. Any solutions regarding this?

Comment: If you're using a binding, use the same `StringFormat`. If you're assignin the value directly to the textblox, you can use `String.PadLeft`: `textBlox.Text = yourNumber.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');`

Comment: Currently I am using the following code: this.lbWeightBlock.Text = lbPopup.LoopingSelector1.DataSource.SelectedItem.ToString() +"." + lbPopup.LoopingSelector2.DataSource.SelectedItem.ToString(); The loopingSelector2 is the one with leading 0 and when using the code above it won't display the leading 0, any suggestions?

Comment: As I said, use PadLeft: `this.lbWeightBlock.Text = lbPopup.LoopingSelector1.DataSource.SelectedItem.ToString() +"." + lbPopup.LoopingSelector2.DataSource.SelectedItem.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');`

Comment: @KooKiz...What a genius you are. It works perfectly fine.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Max Pawlowsky had done a good example of a DigitLoopingSelector with fixed place integers.  I used it in my dfRandomWinner Windows Phone app.

Discussion here - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/cfe453b1-defb-4715-a116-7525641e747c .

Unfortunately it looks like his blog has crashed, but you can read the article and download the code in the google cache of his page - [http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:34K8dvl1I28J:www.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/31/windows-phone-looping-selector-for-digits.aspx+Digitloopingselector&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:34K8dvl1I28J%3awww.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/31/windows-phone-looping-selector-for-digits.aspx%20Digitloopingselector&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

Direct source code link for Max's code - http://www.maxpaulousky.com/storage/20110108-Windows-Phone-7-Looping-Selector-for-Digits/DigitLoopingSelector.zip